# adding styles to HTML and Body using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add these styles I present as CSS to HTML and Body tag using **Javascript**:

```
html, body {
  overflow-y:hidden;
  height:100%;
}
```

The question is HOW?

Comment: The question actually is why ?

Answer (score 1):

That's rather easy:

```
var html = document.documentElement; // <html> tag
var body = document.body; // <body> tag

html.style.height = body.style.height = '100%';
html.style.overflowY = body.style.overflowY = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using querySelector or, if there are multiple instances of the element, querySelectorAll. You do this like this:

```
document.querySelector("html").style.overflowY = "hidden";
document.querySelector("html").style.height = "100%";
document.querySelector("body").style.overflowY = "hidden";
document.querySelector("body").style.height = "100%";
```

If you don't like querySelector, you should know that there is a plethora of different ways to do this, like `document.getElementByTagName("html")`

Comment: syntax error; should be `overflowY`, not `overflow-y`

Comment: @Gershom sorry!! fixed it